# How to set FlowRow last item width equal to other items in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I used `FlowRow` to write the layout, but it kept occupying the width of the last element. How can I make the width of the last element the same as the others?

[image]

```kotlin
    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 12.dp),
        maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        (0..4).forEach { _ ->
            Card(
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                    defaultElevation = 6.dp
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.5f)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
                ) {
                   // Nothing...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use ```LazyVerticalGrid``` becaseu it will work as you have said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace to `LazyVerticalGrid` and it work! Thanks!